# Downloading file from FTP with batch

Tags: apex, batch, ftp

I need to develop a batch which will download a CSV file from a FTP and insert data in Salesforce.com every day.

Is it possible to do that with Apex or an AppExchange please?

I search but no useful response..

Regards
Aurélien

Answer (score 3):

Apex can only communicate through Http(s) protocol.  You could create a proxy service on another platform that is capable of communicating with FTP.  You would then call this service from salesforce.  The service would retrieve the file from the FTP server and return it to salesforce.

There are countless platforms and languages that could accomplish this, but I personally would use heroku and node.  There is a [NPM package for working with FTP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) that would do most the work for you.

Comment: Also, I'm not aware of any app-exchange packages, but that doesn't mean they don't exists.